# Is it ok to have undefined itemscope, or should I pick from available schema?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I'd like to use Microdata for a web page. But none of the existing available schema seem to fit my content. Do I need to stick with only defined schema or can I define my own? Also, can I have an empty `itemscope` or is it better to define?

```html
<h1>Page Title</h1>

(table of contents)
term 1
term 2
...

<div itemscope>
<h2 itemprop="term">1. Piston</h2>

<h3>Definition - What does Piston mean?</h3>
<span itemprop="definition">A definition</span>

<h3>Explanation of Piston</h3>
<span itemprop="explanation">An explanation</span>

<h3>How to use Piston in a sentence.</h3>
<span itemprop="usage">Sentence using term.</span>
</div>
```

I have 10 terms on the same page, each with this same bit of info. Is it ok to have an undefined `itemscope`? Or should I define it something like "car parts"? Or can we not define our own `itemscope` and instead, choose from existing schema structure?

Ran through Google schema tool and it says no warning or errors, but of course gives me the 'unspecified type' and the following.

- `@type`
- `https://search.google.com/term`
- `https://search.google.com/definition`
- `https://search.google.com/usage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** You could use `itemscope` without `itemtype` (like in your example). That would be a local vocabulary, and you can’t expect Microdata consumers to make use of the data.

```html
<div itemscope>
  <p itemprop="term">…</p>
  <p itemprop="definition">…</p>
</div>
```

**Option 2:** You could define and use your own vocabulary. It’s unlikely that many Microdata consumers would make use of the data, though, as most of them only recognize certain vocabularies.

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="https://example.com/my-vocabulary/">
  <p itemprop="term">…</p>
  <p itemprop="definition">…</p>
</div>
```

**Option 3 (preferable):** You could use Schema.org as far as possible, and use your own types/properties where Schema.org doesn’t offer suitable terms. Your own properties would have to be specified as absolute URIs, and your own types would have to be specified as URI values for Schema.org’s [`additionalType`](https://schema.org/additionalType) property. As Schema.org type, you could always use `Thing` if there is no more specific type available.

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
  <link itemprop="additionalType" href="https://example.com/my-vocabulary/CarPartTerm" />
  <p itemprop="https://example.com/my-vocabulary/term">…</p>
  <p itemprop="https://example.com/my-vocabulary/definition">…</p>
</div>
```

---

That said, it could be the case that Schema.org *does* offer suitable types/properties for your case, e.g., maybe [`DefinedTerm` (Pending)](https://pending.schema.org/DefinedTerm). If you think that a useful type/property is missing in Schema.org, you could [propose that it gets added](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues).

Comment: I will use Option 3. I was not aware of the pending DefinedTerm, and that looks like it could be applicable to my situation. I will submit a suggestion for something to add with that. Thanks.